# Android application working in emulator but not in device

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have created aa android application using android 1.6 (api 4) and the android:minSdkVersion is "3". I am using the emulator to run this application is 2.2. Its working fine in the emulator. Then I installed it in to htc hero (android 1.5) and it showing the force shut down error. Why is it so?

Please anybody give me a reason or solution for this problem.

Regards
kris

Comment: Connect you phone via USB and check the log. An error should tell you what to look for.

Comment: You can also add log collector to your app so that error logs are detected and collected from remote devices: http://code.google.com/p/android-send-me-logs/

Comment: Thanks for the reply peter .. i will check  and let you know..

Answer (score 2):

You could take an emulator 1.5, like that you will see you're error with it. be carreful that some element of interface that are allowed with 1.6, aren't in 1.5.

Comment: hi i tried that too ..then i am getting error `Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception`

Comment: next line `java.lang.VerifyError: com.myapp.coctail.CoctailTabActivity`

Comment: I think your correct, i am using setIndicator(View view). which is not in android 1.5 ...am i correct..

Comment: Do you have the stackTrace ? What do you have on you custom tabActivity ?

Comment: ok ..guys ...thanks for the reply...today i learned a new lesson... :)

Comment: sorry nanis i can't give usefull answer mark coz i don't have 15 reputation ...:(

Comment: don't worry, nice to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Even though I don't see the log, which is definitely FUUU, I think you should add the following lines of code to your Android Manifest, if you have not done this already.

```
<supports-screens android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true" android:smallScreens="true"
        android:resizeable="true" android:anyDensity="true" />
```