# Application database related activity works in emulator but not working in device

Tags: android, sqlite, database-connection

I have created an android application using Android (api 15) and the android:minSdkVersion is "8". I am using the 4.1 emulator to run this application.  It's working fine in the emulator, and installs successfully in a device with api 4.1...but when activity starts that uses my `datak` class (database connection file), the application stops working.

The app is a quiz in which there is one question and one possible answer among four.  The database name is "KBC" and is retrieved when i push play the game...but on the device the database isn't retrieved.  I think the device can't find my database file "KBC" location which has all the tables and questions that i pushed in emulator...

In the virtual device file explorer it shows the database kbc in location "data/data/android.kt.banoge.karodpati/databases"

The code for my `datak` class is included below.  I have already looked at many other questions but they are not helpful:

- http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/
- [Android application working in emulator but not in device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5103031/android-application-working-in-emulator-but-not-in-device)

Can anybody please give me a reason or solution for this problem?

```
public class Datak 
{
public static final String QUE = "question";
public static final String A = "optionA";
public static final String B = "optionB";
public static final String C = "optionC";
public static final String D = "optionD";
public static final String ANS = "answer";
public static final String LEV = "level";

private static final String TAG = "DBAdapter";

public static final String played = "played";
public static final String five = "five";
public static final String one = "one";
public static final String second = "second";
public static final String first = "first";


private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "KBC";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "main";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE2 = "main2";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE3 = "main3";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
    "create table "+ DATABASE_TABLE +"("
    + QUE + " text not null,"
    + A + " text not null, " 
    + B + " text not null,"
    + C + " text not null,"
    + D + " text not null," 
    + ANS + " text not null,"
    + LEV + " text not null); ";

private final Context context; 

private DatabaseHelper DBHelper;

private SQLiteDatabase db;

public Datak(Context ctx) 
{
    this.context = ctx;
    DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
}

private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper 
{
    DatabaseHelper(Context context) 
    {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) 
    {
        db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, 
    int newVersion) 
    {
        Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion 
                + " to "
                + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS titles");
        onCreate(db);
    }
}    

public Datak open() throws SQLException 
{
    db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}


public void close() 
{
    DBHelper.close();
}

public Cursor getValue()
{
     return db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {
            QUE, 
            A,
            B,
            C,
            D,
            ANS,LEV
            },
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,null
             );


}
public Cursor getValue2()
{
     return db.query(DATABASE_TABLE2, new String[] {
            QUE, 
            A,
            B,
            C,
            D,
            ANS,LEV
            },
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,null
             );


}
public Cursor getValue3()
{
     return db.query(DATABASE_TABLE3, new String[] {
            QUE, 
            A,
            B,
            C,
            D,
            ANS,LEV
            },
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,null
             );


}
public Cursor getState()
{
     return db.query("states", new String[] {
                played, 
                five,
                one,
                second,
                first
                },
                null,null,null,null,null);


}

public void updateRow(int a) 
{
    final Cursor c1;
    int pl;
 ContentValues CV=new ContentValues();
 c1=db.query("states", new String[] {
        played, 
        five,
        one,
        second,
        first
        },
        null,null,null,null,null);
    c1.moveToPosition(0);

    if(a==1)
    {
        pl=c1.getInt(0);
        pl++;
        CV.put(played, pl); 
    }
    if(a==2)
    {
        pl=c1.getInt(1);
        pl++;
        CV.put(five, pl);
    }
    if(a==3)
    {
        pl=c1.getInt(2);
        pl++;
        CV.put(one, pl);    
    }
    if(a==4)
    {
        pl=c1.getInt(3);
        pl++;
        CV.put(second, pl); 
    }
    if(a==5)
    {
        pl=c1.getInt(4);
        pl++;
        CV.put(first, pl);  
    }

    db.update("states", CV, null, null);
    c1.close();

}
```

---

12-05 19:08:57.158: E/AndroidRuntime(13825): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-05 19:08:57.158: E/AndroidRuntime(13825): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
12-05 19:08:57.158: E/AndroidRuntime(13825):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3069)
12-05 19:08:57.158: E/AndroidRuntime(13825):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3591)
12-05 19:08:57.158: E/AndroidRuntime(13825):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14263)
12-05 19:08:57.158: E/AndroidRuntime(13825):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
12-05 19:08:57.158: E/AndroidRuntime(13825):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-05 19:08:57.158: E/AndroidRuntime(13825):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-05 19:08:57.158: E/AndroidRuntime(13825):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4507)
12-05 19:08:57.158: E/AndroidRuntime(13825):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-05 19:08:57.158: E/AndroidRuntime(13825):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-05 19:08:57.158: E/AndroidRuntime(13825):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
12-05 19:08:57.158: E/AndroidRuntime(13825):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
12-05 19:08:57.158: E/AndroidRuntime(13825):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-05 19:08:57.158: E/AndroidRuntime(13825): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
12-05 19:08:57.158: E/AndroidRuntime(13825):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-05 19:08:57.158: E/AndroidRuntime(13825):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-05 19:08:57.158: E/AndroidRuntime(13825):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3064)
12-05 19:08:57.158: E/AndroidRuntime(13825):    ... 11 more
12-05 19:08:57.158: E/AndroidRuntime(13825): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: states: , while compiling: SELECT played, five, one, second, first FROM states
12-05 19:08:57.158: E/AndroidRuntime(13825):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
12-05 19:08:57.158: E/AndroidRuntime(13825):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:68)
12-05 19:08:57.158: E/AndroidRuntime(13825):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.compileSql(SQLiteProgram.java:143)
12-05 19:08:57.158: E/AndroidRuntime(13825):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.compileAndbindAllArgs(SQLiteProgram.java:361)
12-05 19:08:57.158: E/AndroidRuntime(13825):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.(SQLiteProgram.java:127)
12-05 19:08:57.158: E/AndroidRuntime(13825):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.(SQLiteProgram.java:94)
12-05 19:08:57.158: E/AndroidRuntime(13825):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.(SQLiteQuery.java:53)
12-05 19:08:57.158: E/AndroidRuntime(13825):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:47)
12-05 19:08:57.158: E/AndroidRuntime(13825):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1690)
12-05 19:08:57.158: E/AndroidRuntime(13825):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1575)
12-05 19:08:57.158: E/AndroidRuntime(13825):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1531)
12-05 19:08:57.158: E/AndroidRuntime(13825):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1611)
12-05 19:08:57.158: E/AndroidRuntime(13825):    at com.kt.banoge.karodpati.Datak.updateRow(Datak.java:172)
12-05 19:08:57.158: E/AndroidRuntime(13825):    at com.kt.banoge.karodpati.MainActivity.change(MainActivity.java:66)
12-05 19:08:57.158: E/AndroidRuntime(13825):    ... 14 more
    }

Answer (score 0):

Could you replace  db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS titles");
by  db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);

This might help;)

Serge

Comment: i tried this solution app works on emulator fine but  still not working in device...
ur solution db.execsql involkes onli if i upgrade the database...not for opening the database !!!

Comment: Yes but if you take a look: you try to delete the table "title" while you create the table "main": a side effect might be that the structure of your main table is not up-to-date.

Comment: When you write "the application stops working", do you receive an exception via logcat? What if you debug you application on your device?

Comment: by the way i have 4 tables in kbc.db that i had inserted manualy by sqlite manager...shoud i  have to pass query to create these tables ??

Comment: i debug app on device. below  is my exception log when my device shows "the application stops working".

Comment: Yes I think it is safer to put all table create queries in your helper so that, if your database is created for the first time or recreated (new database version will upgrade your DB: delete tables and recreate them): all your tables will exist